# Adding A Radio Button To Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to add a radio button to my "Accounts" form. However, when selecting the radio button on the form, it doesn't seem to save in show.html.erb nor in the database.

This is  "_form.html.erb"

```
    <%= form_for(@account) do |f| %>
      <% if @account.errors.any? %>
        <div id="error_explanation">

          <h2><%= pluralize(@account.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this account from being saved:</h2>

          <ul>
          <% @account.errors.full_messages.each do |message| %>
            <li><%= message %></li>
          <% end %>
          </ul>
        </div>
      <% end %>

      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :first_name %><br>
        <%= f.text_field :first_name, class: "form-control" %>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :last_name %><br>
        <%= f.text_field :last_name, class: "form-control" %>
        <div class="form-group">

        <%= f.label :return %><br>
        <%= f.radio_button :return,  class: "form-control" %> Returning Client?

        <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :program %><br>
        <%= f.collection_select :program_id, Program.all, :id, :program, {prompt: "Choose a Program"}, {class: "btn btn-default dropdown-toggle"} %>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :address %><br>
        <%= f.text_field :address, class: "form-control" %>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <%= f.label :phone %><br>
        <%= f.text_field :phone, class: "form-control" %>
      </div>
      <div class="actions">
        <%= f.submit class: "btn btn-primary" %>
      </div>
    <% end %>


<!-- end snippet -->
```

Accounts_Controller

```
 class AccountsController < ApplicationController
      before_action :authenticate_user!
      before_action :set_account, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

      respond_to :html

      def index
        @account = Account.all
        respond_with(@account)
      end

      def show
        @notes = Note.where(account_id: @account.id) #Where a note belong to the current account
      end

      def new
        @account = Account.new
        respond_with(@account)
      end

      def edit
      end

      def create
        @account = Account.new(account_params)
        @account.save
        respond_with(@account)
      end

      def update
        @account.update(account_params)
        respond_with(@account)
      end

      def destroy
        @account.destroy
        respond_with(@account)
      end

      private
        def set_account
          @account = Account.find(params[:id])
        end

        def account_params
          params.require(:account).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :return, :program_id, :address, :phone)
        end
    end
```

The migration file I created to add the "return" field to the accounts table. Which added the field to the schema.

```
  class AddReturnToAccounts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :accounts, :return, :boolean, default: false
  end
end
```

Output from Rails server

```
 Parameters: {"id"=>"1"}
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = 1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  Account Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "accounts".* FROM "accounts"  WHERE "accounts"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Program Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "programs".* FROM "programs"  WHERE "programs"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Note Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "notes".* FROM "notes"  WHERE "notes"."account_id" = 1
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Rendered accounts/show.html.erb within layouts/application (4.2ms)
  Rendered layouts/_bootstrap.html.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered layouts/_bootstrap.html.erb (0.1ms)
  Rendered layouts/_navbar.html.erb (0.5ms)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (0.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 82ms (Views: 79.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.7ms)
```

I'm not sure is the value is being passed correctly, I guess that is what I'm missing but I'm not sure.

Comment: Well show the log while you are creating the record. BTW `return` is a reserved Ruby keyword. I have no idea if that's causing the problem. Let's see Please give me what I asked.

Comment: I think the problem is with your column name. You have used return which is an ruby keyword please use different name and try. e.g. return_goods etc.

Comment: Is the above form template actually working? I think this radio_button tag should be something like `<%= f.radio_button :return,  true %>`

Comment: @kangkyu, your answer worked! Simple fix for a problem that I've been working on for quite some time.

Comment: @curtis, You are right, when it comes to boolean check-boxes are preferred. That was also my conclusion after thinking about the logical a little more. This was the end result on my code "<%= f.check_box :return_client %> Returning Client?" which give me my desired out come. BTW, I took the form-control class out because after adding the "true" value, it formatted that line incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

The [`radio_button` form helper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-radio_button) also takes in the value as a parameter. So, the way it is now, the helper method thinks the hash (`{class: "form-control"}`) is the value. The rendered radio button looks something like:

```
<input type="radio" value="{:class=>&quot;form-control&quot;}" name="account[return]" id="account_return_classform-control"> Returning Client?
```

Pass in the value you would like to persist if the radio button is selected:

```
<%= f.radio_button :return, true, class: "form-control" %> Returning Client?
```

This will give you the render input as you'd expect:

```
<input class="form-control" type="radio" value="true" checked="checked" name="account[return]" id="account_return_true">
```

However, when it comes to a `boolean` type, you might want to consider a checkbox instead.